# How to use Schema Registry and AvroConverter in Kafka Source connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to write custom Source and Sink Kafka connectors for MongoDB with schema registry and Avro. I have configured the key and value converters as AvroConverter and the schema registry url in the properties. What code do i have to add in my connector so that it  converts the data to Avro and validates according to the schema ?

Comment: Are you trying to write your own Kafka Connect connector plugin? Or you're trying to use an existing plugin and run it in your environment, and just want help with the configuration file? If the latter, which plugin are you using? What's your source & sink config look like so far?

Comment: I'm writing my own Connector based on an existing [one](https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb). I don't have a problem with the configuration file. I just want to know how to convert my data to Avro to send as a message and ensure that it follows the schema in the schema registry.

Comment: Have you see then Kafka Connect developer guide? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Yes. But it doesn't clarify my doubt. So far, I have configured the source and sink configs and registered schemas in the Schema Registry using Rest APIs. How do I link these Schemas to my connector ?

Comment: You should reference Landoop's existing sinks and can see Debezium's existing sources. Both have Avro support, but basically, then answer is that you don't need to worry about Avro with Connect. You only need to deal with `Struct` Connect data types, then the `AvroConverter` and `JsonConverter` know how to take that data into respective objects.